# Authentication middleware applies to all routes in my app.js file even though I applied to only one route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, middleware

I created a requireAuth middleware and imported it to app.js, In app.js I have also imported all the routes from routes folder. In each each route.js file I have multiple chained routes. When I use auth middleware in one of that file it should apply to only thoose routes inside that route.js file but instead it applies to my entire application.

here is my middleware -

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { User } = require('../models/users');

const requireAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.jwt;

  //check json web token exists & is verified
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(
      token,
      '***********',
      (err, decodedToken) => {
        if (err) {
          res.redirect('/login');
        } else {
          next();
        }
      }
    );
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
};
module.exports = requireAuth;
```

here is my app.js file -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81hyt.png)

```
//Authentication routes
const userAuth = require('./routes/authRoute');

//importing all routes
const homeRoutes = require('./routes/home');
const profile = require('./routes/profile');
const seoRoute = require('./routes/seo');
const semRoutes = require('./routes/sem');
const nptelRoutes = require('./routes/nptel');

app.use('/', userAuth);
app.use('/', homeRoutes);
app.use('/', projectRoute);
app.use('/', profile);
app.use('/', seoRoute);
app.use('/', requireAuth, nptelRoutes);
```

so u see i applied requireAuth middleware to only the last route but it applies to all the routes in my application. nptelRoutes has multiple routes inside, i want this to work on all the routes inside nptelRoutes. e.g. /nptel, /nptel/answer, /nptel/videos

Comment: You've used the same path for every route

Comment: I don't understand. The same path in every route means ??

Comment: All your `app.use()` calls use the same path, `/`. The `requireAuth` middleware is registered against that route so will run for every request

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/express-js-app-use-method#:%7E:text=The%20app.,path%20matches%20the%20defined%20path.) "The `app.use()` method mounts or puts the specified middleware functions at the specified path. This middleware function will be executed only when the base of the requested path matches the defined path."

Since you use the same path for all of your routes, the middleware applies to all of your routes of the same path.

You have to differentiate your route paths to keep them separate like this :

```js
app.use('/', userAuth);
app.use('/home', homeRoutes);
app.use('/project', projectRoute);
app.use('/profile', profile);
app.use('/seoRoute', seoRoute);
app.use('/nptel', requireAuth, nptelRoutes);
```